# IOS Permissions programmatically

Tags: ios, permissions, ios-permissions

I have searched a lot but could not find any relevant answer to my question.
We can ask for permission in IOS and further use in it our application .
but my simple question is, can we turn off permission programmatically?
I know it could be done in device settings but i want to do it in my app setting.
I am working on app in which i have to control my app permissions in my app settings.

Comment: No,  once permissions are requested only the user can modify the permissions settings.  Why would you want to turn a permission off?   Just don't use what ever it is even though you have permission

Comment: for reflecting phone settings into app settings  you have to use settings bundle . By force setting permission may cause app rejection as apple is highly concerned about its user's security

Answer (score 1):

You can not. Programatically you can not override user's decision. If you do not want specific things, you should not ask for its permission.